# removing class from sibling while assigning to clicked element not working

Tags: jquery, class, siblings

I have a slider I've made, the slider part works correctly, but I'm trying to have the thumbs when clicked basically to have a white border when clicked and then go back to grey when another is clicked.  I'm trying to do this through a list using siblings.  There is some extraneous stuff in this JS but it shouldn't' really affect the out come, but all of the JS is for the switching of the borders, this slider runs on css.  Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/qSDfW/12/

the JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".portfolio_thumb_list li:first").addClass("portfolio_slider_thumb_active");
    $(".accordion a:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();

    $(".portfolio_thumb_list li").click(function() {
        $(this)
            .addClass('portfolio_slider_thumb_active') //set the current as active
            .siblings("li") //find sibling h3 elements
            .removeClass("portfolio_slider_thumb_active") // and remove the active from     
    them
            .end() // return selection to the current element
            .next("p") // find the next p
            .slideDown("slow") // and show it
            .siblings("p:visible") // find the other visible p elements
            .slideUp("slow"); // and hide them

            $(this)
                .find('a') // find a under current element
                .addClass('portfolio_slider_thumb_active') // and add active class
                .end() // return to current element
                .siblings('li') // find sibling h3 elements
                .find('a') // find their a elements
                .removeClass('active'); // and remove the active
    });
});​
```

The CSS is:

```
#portfolio_thumb_list {
list-style-type: none;
width: 55px;
height: 16px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 0;
}

.portfolio_slider_thumb{
border:1px solid #555;
height:30px;
width:55px;
margin-top:-15px;
}

.portfolio_slider_thumb_active{
border:1px solid #fff;
height:30px;
width:55px;
margin-top:-15px;
}
```

the HTML is:

```
<ul id="portfolio_thumb_list">


        <li class="portfolio_slider_thumb"><a href="#content-inner-1"><img  
src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/thumbs/detail/space1.jpg" height="30px"   
width="55px"></a></li>

<img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="3px" border="0" 
            style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)"> 

        <li class="portfolio_slider_thumb"><a href="#content-inner-2"><img     
src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/thumbs/detail/space2.jpg" height="30px"  
width="55px"></a></li>
</ul>
```

in the fiddle there's a little more CSS and HTML because I have the whole slider, but I tried to post the more relevant bits here.  Not sure why those thumb borders arn't working.  The first one should be active on load.

Comment: hmmm, it's only 6 sentences long, plus the code.  It could have been 6 sentences and just the jfiddle, but there are people here who get really upset when you don't post code.  I'm not really sure what I could have cut out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.` (class) selector for a DOM element with only an `id` .. for `id` selector you use `#` - your whole `click` function wasn't working .. try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#portfolio_thumb_list  li:first").addClass("portfolio_slider_thumb_active");
    $(".accordion a:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();

    $("#portfolio_thumb_list li").click(function() {
         $("#portfolio_thumb_list li").removeClass('portfolio_slider_thumb_active');
        $(this)
            .addClass('portfolio_slider_thumb_active') //set the current as active
            .end() // return selection to the current element
            .next("p") // find the next p
            .slideDown("slow") // and show it
            .siblings("p:visible") // find the other visible p elements
            .slideUp("slow"); // and hide them
    });

});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qSDfW/15/)

### Update

The reason its not working on your site is because of the following, below are the `<script>` tags in your `<head>` :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/portfolio/portfolio_slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/portfolio/space_animation.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You need to re-arrange them - so that the actual jQuery library (currently the bottom one) is above the others that require jQuery

Comment: awww, thank you very much, always nice when it's something simple, at the same time always feel a little silly, thanks :)

Comment: this might be a bit much to ask, and I completely understand if it is, but I can't for the life of me get this to work in my site. http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_new.html  all of the css and code is there. http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/portfolio/slider_space.css is the css for the slider and http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/portfolio_slider.js is the javascript.  It won't work like this fiddle for some reason http://jsfiddle.net/qSDfW/18/

Comment: @loriensleafs you need to put `jquery.min.js` first - before your script in the `<head>` ... hope that makes sense ? updated my answer with a proper explanation

Comment: yea that does make sense, and that definitely fixes the borders, but the slider doesn't work in site, but does function in the fiddle.  A little frustrating, I just have no idea why.

Comment: @loriensleafs OK .... you have `<head></head><script>lots</script></body>` ... you cant do this ... `<script>` needs to be in either the `<head>` or the `<body>` fix that and I think your sorted :-)

Comment: tried them in the head, still not working, but I'll mess around with it, maybe try a different solution, thanks for being patient with me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @loriensleafs no probs - i really suggest you have a look at [http://getfirebug.com/](http://getfirebug.com/) if you havent already - its invaluable for things like this .... just load the page and look at the console - will show you where the errors are

Comment: @loriensleafs if you look at your source the very first script block is causing you problems `$("#space_launch")` etc - its not valid